# Can't draw on my texture in texture paint mode

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Basically i have a model with a texture. I used gimp and lot of patience to give color to the parts that needed it, but now i have to do little details and i can't do them if i can't directly draw on the model. I know this can be done becouse i've seen some videos. I select a brush but it doesn't work, i press the mouse button and the program even lags a bit when i move it on the model, but nothing changes on the texture. I'm in cycles.
Link to the file
[image]
[image: Problem]

Comment: If you can, share the file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then edit your question and paste the provided link. It could be some setting of material or brush, but in the image they are not completely visible...

Comment: Ok i removed a big part of the model becouse i need it sorry, i left just the buttstock

Comment: Weird, I still can't get what is not working there... but tried appending the object to a new empty file, and I could texture paint it, both in the 3d view and in the uv/image editor... you could try this, maybe.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that too, i think i'll do it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your destination texture loaded as a brush texture, so you are trying to paint on the image with itself.[image: brush from texture] Turn that off, and switch from Dots to Space in the stroke type, and I am able to get paint to drop onto the new image I used since the file doesn't seem to let me open the one you are using.[image: painted stock]